# Augmented reality with java

Tags: android-augmented-reality

im trying to create an augmented reality app using java (android studio) which detects hand gestures. for instance , if i were to make a number 1 hand sign there will be a small graphics that resembles 1 on the screen. i already have an experience creating augmented reality using unity and vufuria but the way it works is by using a targeted image. In my case right now i will be using hand gestures instead of images. Im having a trouble on what tools i should use in order to develop the app. what tools or tech should i possibly use to develop the application ?

Comment: Have you tied google?

Comment: Yes. but most of the result lead me to vufuria and artoolkit which uses markers and images not hand gestures.